# Unusual behavior when overriding `calculate-lisp-indent'

Tags: indentation, variables, advice, dynamic-scoping, nadvice

I've modified `calculate-lisp-indent` as a better solution to the indentation questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166895/customize-elisp-plist-indentation), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49222433/align-symbols-in-plist) and [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10230/how-to-indent-keywords-aligned). By "modified" I mean I overrode the function with advice. After doing this when I restarted emacs and I tried to indent a lisp form, I'd get the error `void-variable calculate-lisp-indent-last-sexp`.

Here's where things get interesting. You may be inclined to think that's it's some problem with the code I added to `calculate-lisp-indent`. But after failing to figuring out what was wrong with the code I added (which by the way didn't even mention `calculate-lisp-indent`), I tried overriding `calculate-lisp-indent` with a function that has the exact same body as `calculate-lisp-indent`. What happened then? I got the same error. Wierd.

Ok, now I started looking at the code for `lisp-indent-function` and I could not find where the variable `calculate-lisp-indent-last-sexp` was set. It looked as if it was just unbound.

Check out the beginning of the `lisp-indent-function`. `calculate-lisp-indent-last-sexp` was used but not defined.

```
 (let ((normal-indent (current-column))
        (orig-point (point)))
    (goto-char (1+ (elt state 1)))
    (parse-partial-sexp (point) calculate-lisp-indent-last-sexp 0 t)
...
```

A small digression: go to say I'm not sure why `parse-partial-sexp` is doing here. Based on it's documentation I thought it just returned the list, but I don't see the value it's returning being stored anywhere. Does it have any (undocumented) side-effects?

So my first though was `calculate-lisp-indent-last-sexp` must be a global variable. But when I tried to describe it with `describe-variable` I couldn't find it.

Also super interesting. I noticed that after restarting emacs and getting the void variable error, if I re-evaluated the function I wrote to override `calculate-lisp-indent` then I don't get errors and my changes to `calculate-lisp-indent` take effect as I would expect.

```
;; If I re-evaluate this, then the indentation works and I get no errors.
(defun void~calculate-lisp-indent (&optional parse-start)
  "Has same body as `calculate-lisp-indent`."
  ...)
```

What is going on here?

EDIT: After starting emacs with the advice I performed a few checks.

```
(foundp #'void~calculate-lisp-indent) ; => t
(advice-member-p #'void~calculate-lisp-indent #'calculate-lisp-indent) ; => a non-nil value
```

This confirms the advice is a defined function and that it is advising `calculate-lisp-indent`. I don't understand why re-evaluating it makes a difference.

Comment: `parse-partial-sexp` has the documented side-effect: "point is set to where parsing stops." (see the docstring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently discussing a potential patch for as an answer to this question.

The code that answers my original question looks like this:

```
(if (or
     (= (point) calculate-lisp-indent-last-sexp)

     (eq (char-after (1+ containing-sexp)) ?:)

     (eq (char-before containing-sexp) ?')

     (let ((quoted-p nil)
           (point nil)
           (positions (nreverse (butlast (elt state 9)))))
      (save-excursion
        (while (and positions (not quoted-p))
         (setq point (pop positions))
         (setq quoted-p
          (or (eq (char-before point) ?')
           (goto-char (1+ point))
           (looking-at-p "[[:space:]\n]*quote\\_>")))))
      quoted-p))
    ;; Containing sexp has nothing before this line
    ;; except the first element.  Indent under that element.
    nil
  ;; Skip the first element, find start of second (the first
  ;; argument of the function call) and indent under.
  (progn (forward-sexp 1)
   (parse-partial-sexp (point)
    calculate-lisp-indent-last-sexp
    0 t)))
```

This patch should be put in the body of `calculate-lisp-indent` (I don't show it in the body here for brevity). It should go where I denote `<<CODE GOES HERE>>`.

```
(defun calculate-lisp-indent ()
  ...
  (cond ((looking-at "\\s(")
         ;; First element of containing sexp is a list.
         ;; Indent under that list.
         )
   ((> (save-excursion (forward-line 1) (point))
     calculate-lisp-indent-last-sexp)
    ;; This is the first line to start within the containing sexp.
    ;; It's almost certainly a function call.
    <<CODE GOES HERE>>>
    (backward-prefix-chars))
   (t ...))
  ...)
```

Here is a demonstration of how this patch works:

```
;; Quoted list
'(hello hi ho
  ho hi)

;; Backquote is not touched
`(hello hi
        ho)

;; Nested quoted list
'((hello hi ho
   hello))

;; Explicitly quoted list
(quote (a b c
        d e f))
```

I will try to update this post in case some detail of this patch changes. You can also see [this link](https://debbugs.gnu.org/db/21/21922.html) to see my progress on this patch.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help with part of your question.  It seems to be a multi-part question, i.e., multiple questions (it's generally better to ask one question at a time).

1. `C-h f calculate-list-indent` tells you the function is defined in `lisp-mode.el`. Clicking on `lisp-mode.el` in `*Help*` visits that library.
2. Searching for `calculate-lisp-indent-last-sexp` in `lisp-mode.el` shows that it is declared as a global/special variable, i.e., a variable that is scoped dynamically.
   That declaration is not a definition - there is no default value assigned, and there is no doc string.

   ```
   (defvar calculate-lisp-indent-last-sexp)
   ```
3. That explains why `describe-variable` describes it only to the extent of saying that its value is void.  The help function doesn't try to say where it was declared (it could be declared in any number of places), and it doesn't show any doc for it because there is none.
4. Searching further for that variable shows that it is **bound** in function `calculate-lisp-indent`.

   ```
   (let ((indent-point (point))
         state
         ;; setting this to a number inhibits calling hook
         (desired-indent nil)
         (retry t)
         calculate-lisp-indent-last-sexp containing-sexp)
     ...)
   ```
5. When a dynamically scoped variable is bound with `let` it is bound for the *duration* of the calling code (the `let`).  It is not bound *lexically* by the `let`.  This means that it remains bound for the *duration* of any code invoked in the `let` body.  That includes the invocation of `lisp-indent-function`: `(funcall lisp-indent-function indent-point state)`.

Comment: I still don't understand why overriding `calculate-lisp-indent` with a function that has an identical body would cause `calculate-lisp-indent-last-sexp` to be void. When I use `describe-variable` it says that `calculate-lisp-indent-last-sexp` is `void as a variable` not that it's value is void as you said (maybe you meant the same thing but I just wanted to clarify). In other words, it's not even bound ( `(boundp 'calculate-lisp-indent-last-sexp)` returns nil). Whereas, I expected it to be bound and set to nil.

Comment: Now that you mention it it does seem like it has to do with lexical/dynamic binding. I set my emacs to lexical binding on startup so maybe this has to do with it. By the way thank you for being patient with me I realize my question is not well worded.

Comment: @Aquaactress Because your definition is missing `(defvar calculate-lisp-indent-last-sexp)` so the `let` has a different effect. See [(elisp) Defining Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Variables.html), particularly "if VALUE is omitted then the variable is only marked special locally (i.e. within the current[...] file[...]".

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. I'll mark your answer as correct if you put it as an answer.

Comment: The sentence "I set my emacs to lexical binding on startup" makes no sense.  lexical-binding is not a *state* of Emacs: it is a property of *code*, hence it's usually attached to files.